# Trying to pass multiple values into a Label

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to return the total meal price into the label totalOrderedLabel. The totalOrderedLabel label is returning 0.0 when I press the orderBtn.  In totalOrderedLabel I want it to show the total Price of the meals selected.

```
ArrayList<Food> OrderedFoodList = new ArrayList<>();    

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void NewScreen() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MenuPage frame = new MenuPage();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public MenuPage() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 845, 363);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

 //     StartPage start = new StartPage(MenuPage.this);
 //             start.setVisible(true);
 //             start.setModal(true);

    menuTxt = new JTextField();
    menuTxt.setBounds(295, 1, 81, 26);
    menuTxt.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    menuTxt.setEditable(false);
    menuTxt.setText("Menu");
    contentPane.add(menuTxt);
    menuTxt.setColumns(10);

    mealSelectTxt = new JTextField();
    mealSelectTxt.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    mealSelectTxt.setEditable(false);
    mealSelectTxt.setText("Please select a meal");
    mealSelectTxt.setBounds(253, 39, 154, 26);
    contentPane.add(mealSelectTxt);
    mealSelectTxt.setColumns(10);

    txtOrder = new JTextField();
    txtOrder.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    txtOrder.setEditable(false);
    txtOrder.setText("Order");
    txtOrder.setBounds(520, 39, 91, 26);
    contentPane.add(txtOrder);
    txtOrder.setColumns(10);

    dLM=new menulist();

    mealList = new JList();
    mealList.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    ListModel mealListModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel
            (new String[] { "Select an item from the menu." });

    mealList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {
            if (!evt.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                menulist model = (menulist) mealList.getModel();
                updateLabel(model);
            }
        }
    });

        mealList.setModel(mealListModel);

    mealList.setBounds(206, 72, 220, 105);
    contentPane.add(mealList);

    starterBtn = new JButton("Starter");
    starterBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            menulist dLM=new menulist();
            dLM.addItem("Tomato Soup", "Creamy Tomato Soup served with a warm crusty bread roll.", "235", 3.90);
            dLM.addItem("Garlic & Cheese Mushrooms (V)", "Baked mushrooms in a garlic and cheese sauce.", "175", 5.60);
            dLM.addItem("Garlic Bread & Cheese Pizza Bread", "Garlic pizza bread with mozzarella cheese.", "480", 5.50);
            dLM.addItem("Bruschetta Napoli (V)", "Crisp ciabatta bread topped with homemade bruschetta.", "430", 4.80);

        }

    }); 

    mainBtn = new JButton("Main");
    mainBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            menulist dLN=new menulist();
            dLN.addItem("Chicken & Chips", "Chicken breast served with a side of chips and vegetables.", "560", 8.30);
            dLN.addItem("Steak","Filet steak served with saute potatoes and mushrooms.","670", 10.90);
            dLN.addItem("American Hot Pizza","Pepperoni, fresh green chilli and mozzarella, on our classic thin crust base.","520", 9.20);
            dLN.addItem("BBQ Cheese Burger","Our classic 100% Irish beef burger, topped with cheese and our signature BBQ sauce, served in a soft Sicilian style bun with baby gem lettuce.","600", 8.50);
            dLN.addItem("Chicken Penne Bake","Penne pasta with chicken, pepperoni, streaky bacon, rocket and Neapolitan sauce, topped with a cheese crumb.", "800", 8.20);
            dLN.addItem("Veggie Burger (V)","A Southern-Italian style mix of red peppers, olives, sundried tomatoes and mozzarella, served in a soft Sicilian style bun with baby gem lettuce, tomato and mayo. Served with golden fries and chilli relish. ", "630", 8.00);
            mealList.setModel(dLN);
        }
    });


    dessertBtn = new JButton("Dessert ");
    dessertBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            menulist dLB=new menulist();
            dLB.addItem("Dairy Ice Cream", "Three scoops of real dairy ice cream with a fan wafer. Choose from: Vanilla, Strawberry, Chocolate, Toffee, Mint Choc Chip, Brownies & Cream or Blueberry.", "440", 4.80);
            dLB.addItem("Vanilla Cheesecake", "The richest, creamiest and most delicious cheesecake you’ll ever taste, topped with a red berry sauce and served with a scoop of real dairy vanilla ice cream.", "390", 5.10);
            dLB.addItem("Brownies & Ice Cream", "Warm chocolate brownies with cream, brownies & cream ice cream and chocolate flavour sauce.", "520", 4.90);
            dLB.addItem("Cinnamon Waffle Crunch", "A warm cinnamon waffle topped with vanilla ice cream, toffee crunch pieces and butterscotch flavour sauce.", "360", 4.60);
            mealList.setModel(dLB);

        }
    });

    JButton drinksBtn = new JButton("Drinks");
    drinksBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            menulist dLD=new menulist();
            dLD.addItem("Diet Coke", "", "1", 1.60);
            dLD.addItem("Coca Cola", "", "130", 1.60);
            dLD.addItem("Orange Juice", "", "80", 1.30);
            dLD.addItem("Still Water", "", "0", 1.50);
            dLD.addItem("Sparkling Water", "", "0", 1.60);
            dLD.addItem("Stella Artois", "", "180", 2.20);
            dLD.addItem("Red Wine", "", "160", 2.60);
            dLD.addItem("White Wine", "", "180", 2.60);


            mealList.setModel(dLD);
        }
    });

    vegBtn = new JButton("Vegetarian (V)");
    vegBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            menulist dLV=new menulist();
            dLV.addItem("Mozerella Dippers (V)", "Crispy breaded Mozzarella with tomato & basil sauce.", "300", 5.30);
            dLV.addItem("BBQ Houmous (V)", "Houmous drizzled with BBQ sauce, served with warm garlic pita and tortilla chips.", "330", 5.10);
            dLV.addItem("Double Layered Nachos (V)", "Tortilla chips, melted cheese. Served with spicy guacamole.", "630", 7.20);
            dLV.addItem("Loaded Potato Skins (V)", "Potato skins filled with melted cheese and vegetables", "360", 6.50);
            dLV.addItem("Four Cheese Pizza (V)", "Goat’s cheese, cheddar, smoked cheese, mozzarella, red onion and fresh thyme, on our classic thin crust base.", "560", 7.60);
            dLV.addItem("Chocolate Fudge (V)", "Three layers of chocolate cake with rich chocolate & fudge filling, served warm with real dairy ice cream.", "450", 4.40);

            mealList.setModel(dLV); 

        }
    });

    vegBtn.setBounds(10, 173, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(vegBtn);

    drinksBtn.setBounds(98, 65, 75, 29);
    contentPane.add(drinksBtn);

    dessertBtn.setBounds(10, 111, 81, 29);
    contentPane.add(dessertBtn);

    mainBtn.setBounds(9, 72, 81, 29);
    contentPane.add(mainBtn);

    starterBtn.setBounds(10, 39, 81, 29);
    contentPane.add(starterBtn);


    menulist listOrder = new menulist();

    orderList = new JList(listOrder);


    orderList.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    orderList.setBounds(457, 72, 241, 105);
    contentPane.add(orderList); 


    JButton orderBtn = new JButton();
    orderBtn.setText("Place Order");
    orderBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int selectionNumber = mealList.getSelectedIndex();
            if (selectionNumber == -1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MenuPage.this, "Please select a meal");
            } else {
                Food orderedMeal = (Food) mealList.getSelectedValue();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MenuPage.this, "You have ordered "        //clear the last order . find a code to do that
                        + orderedMeal + "");

                listOrder.addElement(orderedMeal);

                double totalPrice = 0;
                for(Food food  : OrderedFoodList) {
                    totalPrice = totalPrice + food.getPrice();
                }
                totalOrderedLabel.setText("Total price: " + totalPrice);
                //orderList.clear();
                }

        }

    });
    orderBtn.setBounds(259, 189, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(orderBtn);


    reviewBtn = new JButton("Review Order");
    reviewBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            ReviewOrder nw = new ReviewOrder();         // the new visual class window has been created and called MenuPage. The proceedMenuBtn
            nw.NewScreen(); 
        }
    });
    reviewBtn.setBounds(574, 263, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(reviewBtn);

    priceLabel = new JLabel("Price =£0.00");
    priceLabel.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    priceLabel.setBounds(82, 258, 91, 16);
    contentPane.add(priceLabel);

    descLabel = new JLabel("Description: pick an item from the list ");
    descLabel.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    descLabel.setBounds(166, 258, 396, 16);
    contentPane.add(descLabel); 

    kcalLabel = new JLabel("kcal = 0");
    kcalLabel.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    kcalLabel.setBounds(9, 258, 61, 16);
    contentPane.add(kcalLabel); 


    tableLabel = new JLabel("Table : " + Restaurant.tableNumber);
    tableLabel.setBounds(16, 6, 91, 16);
    contentPane.add(tableLabel);

    JLabel dinersLabel = new JLabel("Diners : " + Restaurant.dinerNumber);
    dinersLabel.setBounds(119, 6, 81, 16);
    contentPane.add(dinersLabel);

    JButton removeButton = new JButton("remove");
    removeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int selectionNumber = orderList.getSelectedIndex();
                if (selectionNumber == -1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MenuPage.this, "Remove Item");
                } else {
                    listOrder.removeElementAt(selectionNumber);
                }
        }
    });
    removeButton.setBounds(585, 189, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(removeButton);

    totalOrderedLabel = new JLabel("Total Price");
    totalOrderedLabel.setBounds(436, 202, 126, 16);
    contentPane.add(totalOrderedLabel);
    }

public void updateLabel(menulist model) {

int selectionNumber = mealList.getSelectedIndex();
if (selectionNumber == -1){
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MenuPage.this, "Please select a meal");
} else {
    Food menulist = (Food) mealList.getSelectedValue();
Food itemFood = (Food) ((menulist) model).getElementAt(selectionNumber);


String description = itemFood.getDescription();                                 // could use this to set table label value.
double price = itemFood.getPrice();
String calories = itemFood.getKCal();

priceLabel.setText("Price = £" + price);
descLabel.setText("Description: " + description);
kcalLabel.setText("Kcal = " + calories);


}
}

public void updateModel(){

    int selectionNumber = mealList.getSelectedIndex();
    Food itemFood = (Food) ((menulist) dLM).getElementAt(selectionNumber);

    //Add new food to current order
        OrderedFoodList.add(itemFood);

}
}
```

Comment: That's not clear at all, maybe you could post some pseudo code explaining what you want? (or some schema)

Comment: What do you want to show in TotalOrderedLabel? Total price?

Comment: In TotalOrderedLabel I want it to show the total price.

Comment: So, iterate over `orderList` calulate the total and update the label...what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I can't comment that's why I'm writing in answer section*

You are not calling the method **updateModel()** which adds the itmes to your `OrderedFoodList`. In addition, you are initializing the dLM in each method. You should explain your code.

Comment: I've now found the problem, there was a duplication in my code which wasn't allowing the total price to pass.