# Trying to create a remove button which removes items from a list

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a remove button which will remove an item from 'order_List'. The button that I have made 'removeButton' removes only one item from the list and after that brings up error messages.

```
    menulist listOrder = new menulist();

    order_List = new JList(listOrder);
    order_List.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    order_List.setBounds(457, 72, 241, 105);
    contentPane.add(order_List);

    JButton order_Btn = new JButton();
    order_Btn.setText("Place Order");
    order_Btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int selectionNumber = meal_List.getSelectedIndex();
            if (selectionNumber == -1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MenuPage.this, "Please select a meal");
            } else {
                Food orderedMeal = (Food) meal_List.getSelectedValue();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MenuPage.this, "You have ordered "        //clear the last order . find a code to do that
                        + orderedMeal + "");
                listOrder.addElement(orderedMeal);
                }
        }

    });

    JButton removeButton = new JButton("remove");
    removeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int selectionNumber = meal_List.getSelectedIndex();
                if (selectionNumber == -1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MenuPage.this, "Remove  Item");
                } else {
                    listOrder.removeElementAt(selectionNumber);
                }
        }
    });
    removeButton.setBounds(585, 189, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(removeButton);
    }
```

error message that appears.

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"       java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 1
at java.util.Vector.removeElementAt(Vector.java:558)
at javax.swing.DefaultListModel.removeElementAt(DefaultListModel.java:331)
at MenuPage$10.actionPerformed(MenuPage.java:293)
```

Comment: Em, would you please mind telling us _what_ error message you see?

Comment: Variable names should not start with an upper case character. Some of your variables are correct others are not. Be consistent! Class names SHOULD start with an upper case character. Your code is extremely difficult to read because the forum highlights based on Java conventions which you are NOT following.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int selectionNumber = meal_List.getSelectedIndex();
```

You get the selected index from the "meal_List".

```
listOrder.removeElementAt(selectionNumber);
```

But you try to delete the item from the "listOrder".

Be consistent and use the same JList for both statements.

Also, be consistent with naming. Why are you using an "_" in one of the JList names? Variable names should NOT contain an underscore. Check out [Java conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java) for some basics.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check out that Java conventions and try to keep all my code consistent.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to take a look at this other issue I am having. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36507397/trying-to-pass-multiple-values-into-a-label