# Error thrown when I click out of ListModel

Tags: java, swing, indexoutofboundsexception, jlist

When I click on a button (e.g mainBtn) then select a String within the mealList and then click on another button (e.g starterBtn) an error is thrown within the console. If someone could nudge me in the right direction and show me why the code is throwing an error message that would be much appreciated.

```
public void updateLabel(menulist model) {


int selectionNumber = mealList.getSelectedIndex();
if (selectionNumber == -1){
} else {
    Food menulist = (Food) mealList.getSelectedValue();
Food itemFood = (Food) ((menulist) model).getElementAt(selectionNumber);
```

Error Message

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"     java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.Vector.elementData(Vector.java:734)
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:477)
at javax.swing.DefaultListModel.getElementAt(DefaultListModel.java:89)
at MenuPage.updateLabel(MenuPage.java:317)
```

Comment: The exception is being thrown at this point -> MenuPage.updateLabel(MenuPage.java:317). Maybe if you copy that method, someone can help you.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Still waiting for you to accept answers when you get help. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36509153/trying-to-create-a-remove-button-which-removes-items-from-a-list. Still waiting for you to use proper variable names. How does "DLM" follows the standard you were given in the above link.

Comment: I have now changed that variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling to an invalid index, whenever you chose the item, you must not be establishing what index value you chose, therefore, the button will register as -1 because of the release of the button, you want to have the index value of the item of choice included with the ActionEvent

Comment: I have added the method now which is where the error message is showing.

Comment: Again, you don't have a valid index position, what you have is essentially an ArrayList of buttons, but when you press the button, the values aren't set to that index which is why you are getting a -1 index, the -1 because the button has been released and the change was marked Instead of the index of your option

Comment: I have added a valid index position and the code now works.