# Trying to update total order list

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to update my totalOrderedLabel so that when I remove an item from the orderList the totalPrice within the totalOrderedLabel will be updated.

Remove Button

```
JButton removeButton = new JButton("remove");
    removeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int selectionNumber = orderList.getSelectedIndex();
                if (selectionNumber == -1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MenuPage.this, "Remove Item");
                } else {
                    listOrder.removeElementAt(selectionNumber);

                    double totalPrice = 0.0;
                    for(Food food  : OrderedFoodList) {
                        totalPrice = totalPrice + food.getPrice(); 
                    }

                    totalOrderedLabel.setText("Total price: " + totalPrice);
                    OrderedFoodList.clear();
                }
        }

    });
    removeButton.setBounds(680, 189, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(removeButton);
```

orderList/method to add up the total price.

```
    menulist listOrder = new menulist();
    orderList = new JList(listOrder);

JButton orderBtn = new JButton();
    orderBtn.setText("Place Order");
    orderBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int selectionNumber = mealList.getSelectedIndex();
            if (selectionNumber == -1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MenuPage.this, "Please select a meal");
            } else {
                Food orderedMeal = (Food) mealList.getSelectedValue();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MenuPage.this, "You have ordered "        //clear the last order . find a code to do that
                        + orderedMeal + "");

                listOrder.addElement(orderedMeal);

                double totalPrice = 0.0;
                for(Food food  : OrderedFoodList) {
                    totalPrice = totalPrice + food.getPrice();
                }
                totalOrderedLabel.setText("Total price: " + totalPrice);

                }
        }

    });
    orderBtn.setBounds(259, 189, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(orderBtn);
```

totalOrdered Label

```
totalOrderedLabel = new JLabel("Total Price");
    totalOrderedLabel.setBounds(697, 111, 142, 16);
    contentPane.add(totalOrderedLabel);

    totalCaloriesLabel = new JLabel("Total Calories");
    totalCaloriesLabel.setBounds(388, 205, 253, 16);
    contentPane.add(totalCaloriesLabel);
    }

public void updateLabel(menulist model) {

int selectionNumber = mealList.getSelectedIndex();
if (selectionNumber == -1){
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MenuPage.this, "Please select a meal");
} else {
    Food menulist = (Food) mealList.getSelectedValue();
Food itemFood = (Food) ((menulist) model).getElementAt(selectionNumber);

//Add new food to current order
OrderedFoodList.add(itemFood);
```

Comment: Best way to do IMO would be to make OrderedFoodList `Observable`, then add `Observer`s for all of the graphical fields that depend on it. On update, remember to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)

Comment: @LydiaRichardson, And what is the exact problem you are having? Do you know how to set the text of a JLabel? Do you know how to iterate through the JList and total up all the values? You appear to do all this logic in your "Place Order" button. So what is different about the "Remove" button?

Comment: Why don't you and your brother work together to solve the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36509153/trying-to-create-a-remove-button-which-removes-items-from-a-list/36509400#36509400 And while your at it remind your brother to start accepting answers when you get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to update my totalOrderedLabel so that when I remove an item from the orderList the totalPrice within the totalOrderedLabel will be updated

And what about when you add a new item to the list? In both cases the concept is the same you iterate through all the items in the list and then update the label.

So you need to be notified when items in the list change. Add a `ListDataListener` to the `ListModel`. Then when the event is generated you iterate through all the remaining items in the list and recalculate the total and then update the JLabel.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a ListDataListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listdatalistener.html) for a working example and more information.